# Exchange online security groups without email

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, security-groups

We're trying to create user groups in Exchange Online in order to group users when applying permissions to specific folder on shared mailboxes.

We don't want to mail-enable those groups, but I don't seem to find way to do it. In Exchange, I can only create O365 Groups, distribution groups and security groups, which are all mail enabled. From Azure AD I can create a security group that's not mail enabled, but it doesn't appear anywhere when setting permissions to folders.

I'm probably missing something important where, but how should I proceed?

Comment: It’s probably not possible. If they aren’t mail enabled how are they going to access the folders in the shared mailbox? Delegated folders are accessed from Outlook or OWA after the user logs in to their own mailbox. If they don’t have a mailbox they can’t use Outlook. Microsoft isn’t going to make it that easy to buy one license and let a bunch of people use it for email. You can enable a login username and password for a shared mailbox and use it like a normal mailbox though where needed.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. I just wanted to have a way to group users when setting up permissions to a shared mailbox folder, instead of applying them for each individual user.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood. I’m still not sure if it’s possible.  Are you saying the other mail enabled groups have the capability you are looking for? What is the concern about a mail enabled group? You can hide it from the exchange GAL and block mail delivery to it if that is your concern.

Comment: Yes, other mail-enabled groups provide that ability. Ok, I guess I can do as you suggest, it just seems awkward. Thank you.